# Where does Google sync my photos?

Tags: sync, google-plus-photos, google-photos

I really don't know where or how to find my photos. I had a Samsung device and I used Google to backup my pictures. Will someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Backed up photos are accessible via [plus.google.com/photos](http://plus.google.com/photos).